# Why do I get FALSE when using identical function in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to compare between 2 values, both numeric and identical, but still get FALSE, any one know what is the reason?

```
 class(merged_01_11$X1_01)
#[1] "numeric"
 class(merged_01_11$X1_11)
#[1] "numeric"
 merged_01_11$X1_11[1]
#[1] 8291870
 merged_01_11$X1_01[1]
#[1] 8291870
 identical(merged_01_11$X1_11[1], merged_01_11$X1_01[1])
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: May be one of them is not equal to `8291870`.  You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: You probably want to use `all.equal`.

Comment: Thanks! it works now with :   isTRUE(all.equal(merged_01_11$X1_11[1], merged_01_11$X1_01[1]))
[1] TRUE

Comment: @RamiKrispin It would be good to understand why `identical` isn't working, can you put in minimal data to reproduce, perhaps just one line from each data frame ?

Comment: @steveb; its due to floating point differences  - see the link in Akrun's comment. <but an example using the number from the post: `x <- 8291870 ; y <- exp(log(x)) ; y ; identical(x,y) ; print(y, digits=20)` >